Preparing a box diagram for representing accuracy metrics
Following is the portion of data I have:



Parameter
Method
RMSE
MAE
FID




DRCT
CubicInterpolation
80.0887
87.9013
8375.7247


DRCT
KrigingInterpolation
49.3513
70.9927
3823.2367


DRCT
LSTM
84.6987
98.1393
11957


DRCT
LinearInterpolation
36.752
35.6747
134.3787


DRCT
PolynomialInterpolation
48.3893
70.502
6116.5867


DRCT
SplineInterpolation
72.8787
45.774
41.7713


DRCT
VAE
102.5967
90.9553
10570.3807


DRCT
cGAN
0.3267
0.3447
0.0587


DWPT
CubicInterpolation
23.2107
28.142
1088.6787


DWPT
KrigingInterpolation
20.348
25.9827
842.3687


DWPT
LSTM
30.4353
45.2293
2797.9993


DWPT
LinearInterpolation
19.686
3.5553
7.8667


DWPT
PolynomialInterpolation
11.9107
17.8107
517.4547


DWPT
SplineInterpolation
7.2767
4.7913
11.3773


DWPT
VAE
11.948
27.9
1162.7693


DWPT
cGAN
0.2487
0.2907
0.0953



I am trying to create a diagram to represent Mean Absolute Error (MAE) comparison for different parameters, i.e., DRCT, DWPT across different methods. The horizontal axis will be used for representing the parameters. There is no vertical axis. Instead, I am looking to create a box for each parameter. The box will represent the MAE. The bottom and top will represent the min and max of MAE for the parameter. MAE from other methods will be represented as points or lines inside the box.
Can someone help me to achieve this? I'm clueless at the moment; regular box plots won't do.
expected figure is attached below. I created it using paint. sorry for the less details.

It would help to provide a schematic of the expected graph with the values (and computations) that match your example

I have updated a representative figure now.

Hopefully, this is what you wanted:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Parameter': ['DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DRCT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT', 'DWPT'],
    'MAE': [87.9013, 70.9927, 98.1393, 35.6747, 70.502, 45.774, 90.9553, 0.3447, 28.142, 25.9827, 45.2293, 3.5553, 17.8107, 4.7913, 27.9, 0.2907]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.boxplot(x='MAE', y='Parameter', data=df, orient='h')
sns.stripplot(x='MAE', y='Parameter', data=df, color='orange', jitter=0.2, size=5)

plt.title('Horizontal Boxplot of MAE by Parameter')
plt.xlabel('MAE')
plt.ylabel('Parameter')
plt.show()



AFAIK, there is no direct way to do this, but you can use lower level matplotlib. I am assuming here that all parameters have the same methods in the same order (if not, you'll need to handle the color/legends):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

required = ['q1', 'med', 'q3', 'whislo', 'whishi']

dicts = {}
vals = []

# compute min/max for boxes
for k, g in df.set_index('Method').groupby('Parameter')['MAE']:
    dicts[k] = (g.agg(['min', 'max'])
                 .rename({'min': 'q1', 'max': 'q3'})
                 .reindex(required)
                 .to_dict()
               )
    vals.append(g)

# box width
w = 0.2
    
# plot boxes
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.bxp(dicts.values(),
       widths=np.repeat(w, len(dicts)),
       showfliers=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(list(dicts))

# plot lines
cmap = matplotlib.colormaps['tab10']
for i, v in enumerate(vals, start=1):
    lc = LineCollection([[(i-w/2, y), (i+w/2, y)] for y in v],
                        colors=cmap.colors[:len(v)]
                       )
    ax.add_collection(lc)

# add legend
colors=cmap.colors[:len(v)]
ax.legend([Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], color=c) for c in colors],
          v.index
         )

Output:

